# I have a JSON object of form data in Angular. I need to store it in SQL database table. I am using .NET Core 3.1

Tags: mysql, asp.net, angular, api, post

Steps asked me to do are:

1. Create a stored procedure
2. Create a model then interface and then repository
3. Then create the controller for `[HttpPost]`

Can someone write the detailed steps or code on how to do this?

I am also confused how to store data as the output data (JSON) is not in order of table order.

I've attached the output object from the form.

[image]

Comment: Okay. I've added the tag. We're using MySQL.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.